# Intel Joule and Ubuntu core integration and Drivers

Tags: drivers, hardware, development, ubuntu-core, testing

What devices and peripherals are supported and tested with the Intel Tuchuck development board, with the Intel Joule running Ubuntu core?

```
SPI
I2C
PWM
GPIO
....
mraa(?)
```

What devices and peripherals are supported and tested with the Intel Tuchuck development board, with the Intel Joule running Ubuntu Desktop?

Comment: You can check https://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/mraa/index.html   and https://software.intel.com/en-us/iot/hardware/sensors for list of libraries and supported sensors for the boards. As far as the Ubuntu core is concerned, as long as you run Python, Java,Node.js C++  all the mentioned libraries (mraa) and sensors should theoretically work. Good luck.

Comment: Ubuntu core and mraa from command line. Latest Testing results for GPIO Pins:
Sudo mraa-gpio set [pin#] [1/0]  // verify both on and off
Failure Pins: 1,27, 35 – crashes of core, 63, 67, 69, 72, 74, 76, 78, 79, 80
Failure Pins 71 – 73 – 75 - 77 was originally high, set low, unable to set high. “get” returns 1, and sets pin high!

(classic)f@localhost:~$ sudo mraa-gpio get 77
Pin 77 = 1
(classic)f@localhost:~$ sudo mraa-gpio setraw 77 0
Could not init gpio 77

Successful Pins: 2,4,5, 6, 8, 10,12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 26, 28, 30, 32, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 64, 65, 66, 68, 70,

Comment: Preliminary testing with I2C appears good (mraa-i2c, and C++ code). SPI does not appear to work.